# Selenium find_element_by_id not returning full element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This seems like suspect behavior to me:

Using Selenium and Chrome webdriver (python 3.8.5 on Ubuntu 20.04), I'm not getting the full webElement back from  `find_element_by_id`. If I just wasn't getting anything, I'd think pilot error, but I'm getting PART of the element.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
...
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options, executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get(URL)

inventory_exists = True
try:
    table = driver.find_element_by_id('inventoryTableBody')
    print(table.text) 
except:
    inventory_exists = False
...
```

Here's the HTML of the webElement I'm expecting to grab with that method `inventoryTableBody`:
[image: cap of inventoryTableBody]

I'm getting the first 5 DIVs in that group, but the rest are empty. The rest of the DIVs are there, because when I then `find_elements_by_class_name('wrapper')` on that inventoryTableBody, and then `for w in wrappers` to populate a dictionary, I get a `len()` of 10 on that dictionary. The first 5 are populated with data, but the last 5 (actually the rest, because sometimes there are 12 and I still only get the first 5) are completely empty. I can still loop through them, and count them, but there is no text.

I have the `implicitly_wait()` in there because I wanted to be sure it wasn't a result of returning too fast. Doesn't matter if `the wait()` is 10 seconds or 20 seconds, I still only get the first 5 child elements.

Oh, and the page is built dynamically, so `urlopen()` just gets the base HTML with a loading placeholder (thus Selenium):

```
<div id="inventoryTableBody">
   <div class="loading">

      <div class="logo-spin "></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Sample URL is: https://www.lcbo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/PhysicalStoreInventoryView?langId=-1&storeId=10203&catalogId=10051&productId=65616

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Does scrolling what is in viewport change which items show values?

Comment: show URL for this page

Comment: many pages are `"lazy"` and they load data only when user scroll page or click (sub)tab or unfold element. And you have to do the same in code. Code has to behave like real user.

Comment: Sample URL is https://www.lcbo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/PhysicalStoreInventoryView?langId=-1&storeId=10203&catalogId=10051&productId=65616

Page doesn't appear lazy... full table is displayed on a refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I visit the website, there is a language selector to choose between English and French. You can notice the scroll only appears when you choose one of the options. That said, I used the following code to send a TAB + ENTER keyboard combination, choosing one of the languages and I was able to extract all rows.

The code also waits for the language selector div to be invisible and waits the visibility of all `wrapper` elements.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

URL = 'https://www.lcbo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/PhysicalStoreInventoryView?langId=-1&storeId=10203&catalogId=10051&productId=65616#'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(URL)
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
sleep(1)
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'language-selector')))


inventory_exists = True
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'wrapper')))
    table = driver.find_element_by_id('inventoryTableBody')
    print(table.text)
except TimeoutException:
    inventory_exists = False
except:
    inventory_exists = False
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Genius!  I hadn't even thought that the webdriver would never have accepted a language... I was just comparing to my browser window, which of course had an accepted language. Thanks for this.

Comment: The only change I made was to remove the "wait until all 'wrapper' elements are loaded", because if there was no inventory on that particular product, there would be no wrapper elements on the page, and the wait would time out and break. Still - works great. Thanks again!

Comment: I edited the answer to catch the selenium `TimeoutException` as you said. It's never good to use a bare except.